# Lua Removing first couple characters without add a space

Tags: lua, chars

I'm new to Lua and I'm sure this is a silly problem.

I was trying to remove first 3 characters from a string with string.gsub
Here is the code:

```
string.gsub(m, "/jk", "", 1)
```

Now "/jk" are the first 3 chars the string, now, string.gsub adds a space instead of removing them. My question is, how to remove them without adding the space?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`string.gsub` doesn't add a space unless you ask it to, and in your pasted code you aren't asking it to. Are you sure there wasn't already a space after the `/jk` in the string?

Also, if you're just trying to remove the first 3 characters, you should use `string.sub(m, 4)`.